# How set Tags And Groups field set to NOT "collapsed on display"

Tags: fields

Using Drupal 7 and CIVI CRM 5.x on windows 10 and Xampp

I can set this up in custom fields sets, but how do I set the native "tags and groups" field to expanded on initial display?

[image]

Comment: wonder if in future https://civicrm.org/blog/colemanw/want-to-customize-the-contact-summary-screen may offer that option

Comment: That's excellent, how can I get notified when it does?

Comment: maybe write a comment on the blog?

Comment: or offer to fund coleman to add it - am sure he would then notify you when ready ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add on to @oskylark answer I would use an extra template instead of a duplicate. Easier to manage when upgrading. https://civicrm.org/blog/dave-greenberg/now-its-easier-add-custom-behaviors-templates

In the extra template (TagsAndGroups.extra.tpl) and you could throw some javascript in a {literal} tag along the lines of

```
cj('.crm-tagGroup-accordion').collapse('toggle');
```

NOTE: I did not test this js line, just a first guess.

Comment: Yes, that would work, but I would need the exact code, not just a "first guess" ;) I'll wait and see if a pro provide the code...!Thanks Ray;)

Comment: Maybe I should have said a 'first pass'. I'm not able to do the testing for you but I'd imagine the line is close. I can share links to references on jquery collapse is you need.

Comment: That would be great, I'm learning JS now, so would be a good exercise for me;)

Comment: The civicrm blog link will have the details on using the {literal} tag in a template file - you need those to utilize javascript. (cj is what I'm accustomed to but I believe it is the older way of calling javascript in Civi, you may be able to use CRM.$ instead.) W3 schools usually has good references and examples - in this one: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_collapse.asp they explain collapse and toggle an give an example of target a div thru class.

Answer (score 2):

In your custom Civi templates folder (probably default/civicrm/templates) place a copy of the following file from the civicrm module:
/civicrm/templates/CRM/Contact/Form/Edit/TagsAndGroups.tpl

Edit that file, look for the following line and remove the "collapsed" class:

```
<div class="crm-accordion-wrapper crm-tagGroup-accordion collapsed">
```

No doubt it could also be done without the need of a custom version of this template file by using a couple of lines of jQuery, as long as they run after the initial page load scripts have run. I'll leave that option for a separate answer. Update: see @RayWright's answer, that's how to do it.